# How can I limit rows based on one column?

Tags: sql, select, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with columns for osi_key (identification #), value, and time.
I would like to find out when each osi_key reached its Max value.
I have written a SQL query that does this:

```
SELECT t1.osi_key, t1.time, t1.value
FROM
(
SELECT osi_key, MAX(value) AS max_value
FROM data_values_6_2020
WHERE value > 0
GROUP BY osi_key
) AS t2
INNER JOIN data_values_6_2020 AS t1
ON t1.osi_key = t2.osi_key
AND t1.value = t2.max_value
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXmSi.jpg)

However, if it sees duplicate MAX values for the same osi_key, it will return all rows that have unique time stamps.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVDpo.jpg)

I would like it to ignore multiple time stamps and only return one row for each OSI_key.  Maybe the latest time stamp to look like this:

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ2bv.jpg)

Is this possible?

Comment: Please add tags to your question to let others know which DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select osi_key, time, value
from (
    select 
        d.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by osi_key order by value desc, time desc) rn
    from data_values_6_2020 d
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the MAX of t1.time:

```
SELECT t1.osi_key, MAX(t1.time), t1.value FROM ( SELECT osi_key, MAX(value)
AS max_value FROM data_values_6_2020 WHERE value > 0 GROUP BY osi_key ) AS t2
INNER JOIN data_values_6_2020 AS t1 ON t1.osi_key = t2.osi_key AND t1.value =
t2.max_value
GROUP BY t1.osi_key, t1.osi_key
```

But since you are taking the values and the data from the same table is simplier:

```
SELECT osi_key, MAX(time) as maxTime, MAX(value) as maxValue from data_values_6_2020
group by osi_key
```

Comment: I readed back your question, and my answer is not completly true. It gets the MAX value and the last date the osi_key was changed… It's not always true that the last date corrispond at the max value...

Comment: You're right, it didn't quite get me to the result I wanted because the returned date did not correspond with the max value.  But thanks for trying.